# background noice when recording audio on pc but not when recording on laptop

Tags: sound, microphone, audacity

when I record audio on my pc it has a background noice that doesnt go away,
but whenever I record on my laptop with the same microphone it doesnt have that background nice

both machines are running the latest LTS of ubuntu gnome

I tested this with both my zeepin bm-800 and steelseries siberia 200 headphones

here is a link to i screenshot of audacity when recording
[image]
any help is very appreciated

Comment: check alsa capture devices. mute and zero levels for unused inputs

Comment: I only had 1 input device pluged in when recording

Comment: if another device is turned on and set to a high level it might be generating the noise. if that is the case you turn off the unused device and noise stops. if there is still noise problem, need to investigate problem with software/hardware further.
if you cannot deal with alsamixer - use command 'amixer -c 0' in terminal and add that information to your post